# iBeacon Data Encryption (Advertising Mode)

Tags: encryption, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ads

my goal is to encrypt iBeacon data (UUID+MajorID+MinorID: 20 bytes),  preferably with a timestamp included (encrypted and plain), thus summing up to around 31/32 bytes. 
As you have already found out, this exceeds the maximum allowed iBeacon Data (31 bytes, including iBeacon prefix and tx power).
Thus, encryption  only works by creating a custom beacon format instead of the iBeacon format? 
Talking about encryption: I would think about using a symmetrical cipher using CBC operation mode (to avoid decipher due to repetition, and most important to avoid cipher text adjustments resulting in a changed UUID, Major-/MinorID). It's not problem to make the IV (Initialization Vector) public (unencrypted), right? 
Remember, the iBeacons work in advertising mode (transfer only), without being connected to beforehand, thus I am not able to exchange an initialization vector (IV) before any data is sent.
Which considerations should be made using the most appropriate cipher algorithm? Is AES-128 OK? With or without padding-scheme? I also thought about a AES-GCM constellation, but I don't this it's really necessary/applicable due to the used advertising mode. How should I exchange session tokens? Moreover, there's no real session in my case, the iBeacons send data 24/7, open end, without a real initialization of a connection.
Suppose a system containing of 100 iBeacons, 20 devices and 1 application. Each iBeacon sends data periodically (i.e. 500ms), being received by near devices via BLE, that forward the data to an application via udp.
So the system overview relation is:

n iBeacons -(ble)- k devices -(udp)- 1 Application

Is it acceptable to use the same encryption key on each iBeacon? If I would work with a tuple (iBeacon Id / encryption key), i would additionally have to add the iBeacon Id to each packet, thus being able to lookup the key in a dictionary.
Should the data be decrypted on the device or only later in the application?

Comment: Can you clarify your maximum data length?  Exactly 31 bytes are allowed or?

Comment: @Luke: iBeacon allows 31 bytes of data, while 30 bytes are generally used (9(iBeacon prefix)/16(UUID)/2(MajorId)/2(MinorId)/1(TX Power)).

Comment: 31 bytes isn't much to work with if you want full security.  Consider CTR mode instead of CBC.

Comment: You don't state what platforms you are targeting to receive the information, but on iOS the UUID for the iBeacons you are looking for must be provided; you cannot scan for iBeacons promiscuously.  This means that you have only 64 bits to encode your data (major and minor).

Comment: @Luke: Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Paulw11: I don't depend on iOS, furthermore the question can be seen as a theoretical problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the [Eddystone-EID spec](https://developers.google.com/beacons/eddystone-eid-preprint.pdf) to see how Google tried to solve a similar problem.

I'm not an expert on all the issues you bring up, but I think Google offers a good solution for your first question:  **how can you get your encrypted payload to fit in the small number of bytes available to a beacon packet?**

Their answer is: **you don't.** They solve this problem by truncating the encrypted payload to make a hash, and then using an online service to "resolve" this hash and see if it matches any of your beacons.  The online service simply performs the same hashing algorithm against every beacon you have registered, and see if it comes up with the same value for the time period.  If so, it can convert the encrypted hash identifier into a useful one.

Before you go too far with this approach, be sure to consider @Paulw11's point that on iOS devices you can must know the 16-byte iBeacon UUID up front or the operating system blocks you from reading the rest of the packet.  For this reason, you may have to stick with the Android platform if using iBeacon, or switch to the similar [AltBeacon](http://altbeacon.org/) format that does not have this restriction on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your excellent post, I hadn't heard about the Eddystone spec before, it's really something to look into, and it has a maximum payload length of 31 bytes, just like iBeacon. In the paper it is written that in general, it is an encryption of a timestamp value (since a pre-defined epoch). Did I get the processing steps right?

1. Define secret keys (EIKs) for each beacon and share those keys with another resolver or server (if there's a constellation without a online resource);
2. Create lookup tables on the server with a PRF (like AES CTR);
3. Encrypt timestamp on beacon with PRF(i.e. AES CTR?) and send data in Eddystone format to resolver/server;
4. Server compares received ciphertext with entries in lookup table, thus knows about the beacon id, because each beacon has a unique secret key, which leads to a different ciphertext
5. Would it work the same way with AES-EAX? All I'd have to put into the algorithm is an IV(nonce value) as well as the key and message? The other end would build the same tuple to compare ciphertext and tag'?

Question: What about the IRK (identity resolution key), what is it? Which nonce would be used for AES CTR? Would each beacon use the same nonce? It has to be known to the resolver/server, too.
What about time synchronization? There's no real connection between beacon and resolver/server, but is it assumed that both ends are synchronized with the same time server? Or how should beacon and resolver/server get the same ciphertext, if one end works in the year 2011, while the resolver has arrived in 2017?